# VBA: How to put borders around ceration ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with a macro that places thick borders around certain ranges. I've included an example that illustrates the problem.

I will appreciate if you can help me with this issue.

https://app.box.com/s/i0qi02agje7pzf2it3jlds0w8atsplnu

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code, and try to say exactly what your problem is?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want inside vertical or inside horizontal:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:B10").BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThick
```

Answer (score -1):

Macro recorder gave me:

```
Range("F10:G13").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
```

Clean it up a bit

```
With Range("F10:G13")
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End With
```

Could put this in a function and pass it a range.

Comment: In this case, that is way to much code, but is what Macro Recorder spits out. Also, Functions should RETURN something, not DO something like adjust formatting, that is for SUBS.